# ng build drops a ton of errors on a project which worked fine during development

Tags: angular

I've just finished my first own Angular project (applause), but when I try to deploy it, `ng build` throws a gazillion of errors. They are mostly about properties or values which do not exist, but it also has a problem with `private` variables.

I am sure there must be a switch to ignore these errors, but which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume these errors are coming from the AOT compiler. I believe you can turn off AOT using the aot flag. But then you won't get the benefits of the AOT compiler.

Comment: I already tried npm build --aot=false. It still doesn't work. I am getting a ton of error messages both on Windows and Ubuntu, while ng serve works on Windows but not on Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you think this is what I need?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: That is what you are getting when you do a ng build for production.

Comment: I just talked to someone that works on the CLI. They said that the ng build does some additional static code analysis and that is why you are seeing those errors. He said that the best way to deal with this issue is to fix the reported coding errors.

Comment: That sounds really silly. Those are not actual errors. Unless of course, using private variables is an error. Surely there must be a way to adjust the paranoia of the CLI because this is ridiculous.

Comment: I believe using private variables is considered to be an error if the template is trying to use/bind to them. This is important to be resolved for the AOT.

Comment: Well, I updated typescript, and now it builds finely. That is funny because it's the same version as before, 2.3.0